# Level Up Event Firebase on Unity dosent Work properly

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

hope that someone can clarify this for me :

I want to implement Firebase level up event on my Game but it only shows the Level number 0 other Levels doesn't show Up, I have a script attached to the Prefab like this :

```
public class LevelLog : MonoBehaviour {

public string levelNumber;
void Start () {

    Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(
     Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.EventLevelUp,
       new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter[] {
           new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter(
            Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.ParameterLevel, levelNumber),


  }
);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

and each level has Number but Firebase only Shows the Level number 0 and it dosent shows the other levels , i have attached Screenshot for the Problem bellow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5xHL.png)

Comment: Have you turned on debug mode and made sure that you have sent some events with different level number and seen those events on the DebugView? Just to be sure that the levelNumber is not always 0. Also, you may want to wait for a few hours so Firebase can aggregate

Comment: on the Streamview i can see multiple level number not only the level number 0 ,this is a weird Problem and today i have checked the Firebase Console,and  it dosent show now any level number even the level number 0 cannot be shown ,no data at all simply gone.

Comment: So it looks like your data made it to the server and it is waiting to be processed. From my experience with the parameters of some events, it might take a few days. I don't know the reason why though. Maybe wait 2-3 days and contact the Firebase support directly if the problem still persists.